# basic while loop concept

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

Here is the correct code for evaluating if two strings are equal in length and character.

```
function equal(x, y) {
    if(x.length != y.length)
         return false
    var i = 0;
    while(i < x.length) {
       if(x.charAt(i) != y.charAt(i))
          return false
       i++
    }
    return true
  }

equal("hello", "hello") // true
equal("hello", "heyyy") // false
```

I modified it on my own in which I think logical for me. But my code(shown below) returns true while their character content is different. Can any one help me what is wrong with my version?

```
function equal(x, y) {
  if(x.length != y.length)
     return false
  var i = 0;
  while(i < x.length) {
     if(x.charAt(i) != y.charAt(i))
        return false
     else return true
    i++
   }
}

equal("hello", "hi") //false
equal("hello", "heyyy") //true
```

Comment: you are returning true when the first characters are equal

Comment: Missing semicolons all over the place

Comment: Also, [beware the "heyyy" string](http://i.imgur.com/ZUROJvc.png) (slight NSFW language)

Comment: Who upvotes this? There is even working code presented as comparison, so what is the problem with trying to debug the code and actually actively do something?

Comment: I am not a pro like most of you and I need to understand the basics before debugging my fault.

Comment: Still you could have maybe checked what the differences between your code and the working code are and then used [this](https://google.com) to check what makes the difference between the working and your code

Answer (score 5):

It's because you return true on the first iteration of the loop:

```
 if(x.charAt(i) != y.charAt(i))
    return false
 else return true
```

You need to return true at the end of the function:

```
function equal(x, y){
  if(x.length != y.length)
     return false
  var i = 0;
  while(i < x.length){
     if(x.charAt(i) != y.charAt(i))
        return false
    i++
   }
   return true
}
```

Also personally, I'd do this in a for loop :)

You also might run into a problem with things being out of bounds.  Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/73yXY/) showing what happens when you have inconsistent lengths.  Thankfully you do a length check, though, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: +1. This is what I wanted to have written but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

You return `true` in the first iteration of the loop if the characters are equal. This basically guarantees a loop exit after just one character, which is not what you want. Delete the `else return true` clause and add a `return true` after the while loop and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your use of the return statement. The first example evaluates to false because the two strings are not both of the same length. The second is a false positive because you return true and exit the loop if **any** character is equal to another and not if **all** characters are equal.

To fix it just move the return statement:

```
function equal(x, y){
  if(x.length != y.length)
         return false
  var i = 0;
  while(i < x.length){
      if(x.charAt(i) != y.charAt(i))
        return false
      // else return true | move this to bottom to ensure correctness
      i++
  }
  return true // here if nothing was found in the first two steps, they must be equal
}
```